# child_process.fork() in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

Is it possible to fork a child_process from an electron render process? I found some posts across the net, but there were no hint how helps me to get my code working. 
I created a module, that fork child processes. This code works, when I run this with cmd and under node. But when I try to integrate it in my electron app, I can not communicate with the child.send() method.

```
// create fork
const fork = require('child_process').fork;
const fs = require('fs');

const img_path = [
'path/to/an/image1.jpg',
'path/to/an/image2.jpg',
'path/to/an/image3.jpg'
];

const cp = [];

const temp_path = img_path.map((item) => item);

createAndResize(2);

function createAndResize(num) {
    return childResize(createChildProcess(num));
}

function createChildProcess(num) {
    if(num <= 0) {
        return cp;
    } else {
        let cf = fork('./child.js');
        cp.push(cf);
        num -= 1;
        return createChildProcess(num);
    }
}

function childResize(list) {
    if(list.length <=0) {
        return true;
    } else {
     // child_process is created
        let child = list.shift();

         child.on('message', function (data) { 
                if (!temp_path.length) {
                    process.kill(data);
                } else {
                    child.send(temp_path.shift());  
                }
            });

            child.send(temp_path.shift());   

            setTimeout(function() {
                childResize(list);
            }, 1000);      
    }
}

//child.js
process.on('message', function(msg) {
console.log(msg); //this is never reached
};
```

EDIT: based on the comment below, I fork child processes on the main process. The comunication seems to work with few exceptions. But first my new code:

```
    // myView.js
    const { remote } = require('electron');
    const mainProcess = remote.require('./main.js');
    const { forkChildfromMain } = mainProcess;

    forkChildfromMain();


    // main.js
        const fork = require('child_process').fork;
        let cp = [];



function forkChildfromMain() { 
    createAndResize(4);
}

function createAndResize(num) {
        return childResize(createChildProcess(num));
    }
    function createChildProcess(num) {
        if(num <= 0) {
            return cp;
        } else {
            let cf = fork('./resize.js');
            cp.push(cf);
            num -= 1;
            return createChildProcess(num);
        }
    }

    function childResize(list) {
        if(list.length <=0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            let child = list.shift();

             child.on('message', function (msg) {
    // logs 'Hello World' to the cmd console
    console.log(msg);
    });
                child.send('Hello World');   
                setTimeout(function() {
                    childResize(list);
                }, 1000);      
        }
    }

exports.forkChildfromMain = forkChildfromMain;


    // child.js
    process.on('message', function(msg) {
    // this console statement get never loged
    // I think, I must integrate an icpModule
        console.log(msg);

    //process send msg back to main.js
    process.send(msg);
    })
```

OUTDATED: The main problem now is, that I think electron 'spawn' new child processes and do not fork. 
Because, when I look at my task manager I see only one instance from electron. When I run the code in a node env, I see there were fork multiple node instances.

The reason why I prefer to fork my child processes in multiple node instances is, that I want to make many image manipulation. So when I fork childs, then every child has it own node instance with memory and so on. I think that would be more performant then when I only have one instance who shared the memory and resources to all of the childs.

The second unexpected behavior is, that the console.log statement in the child is not printed to my cmd console. But this is the smaller ones :)

EDIT: After I analyse my task manager a little more in depth, I saw, that electron spawn multiple child processes like it should.

Answer (score 3):

Electron's renderer process is not the right place for forking child processes, you should think about moving this to the main process.

Nonetheless, it should work the way you describe. If you'd make a minimal example available somewhere I could take a closer look.

Comment: can you explain why the render process is not the place to fork a child process? I have try to fork a child in the main process, too. But it was the same problem. I will try it again and past a new code soon.

Comment: After I realized that I can't log msg from the child, I tried my first code again and it worked. But I'am still interested in your statement why you think the render process is not the right place for create child process.

Comment: @Zantinger, the renderer process is the place where your UI code lives, and for many modules it makes sense to let them live in the renderer process even if (in a client/server application you would put them on the server). Debugging the renderer process is so much easier thanks to Chrome DevTools.
However, for functionality that depends on the OS (like forking) it usually makes sense to put it into the main process. There's usually not much code in the main processes of my applications but like I mentioned calls that depend on the OS i place there and I've never regretted this choice.

Comment: But actually, for small applications it might make sense to keep the main as simple as possible.